# Distortion of Farsi alphabets to unknown alphabets

Tags: conversion, xepersian

I have some `TeX` files (including formulas, tables, etc.) written under DOS (but the format is .tex), and want to read them by `LaTeX`. The language is Farsi. I tried to open the `TeX` files with Texmaker and Tex Studio, but sadly everything is messy. Instead of Farsi letters, I see some bizarre symbols! As an example, I have copied a line of code here.

```
‎íø ÏÑ »õ§ $isP\$‎ ‎À¾ ÌÑè‎ ‎ýÑ í÷Êì‎Äöû¾ Ä¾Àãþ ½Ò $x$ ÷ $ihprav\$
```

For example, you see the last expression is `ihprav\` but the correct one is `\varphi`. Also, the Farsi letters are converted to those symbols you see. The real Farsi sentences are like من خوشحالم and so on.

I have made a new file and copied a paragraph of the old file below:

```
 ‎\documentclass{article}‎
 ‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
 ‎\settextfont{Yas}‎

 \title{لاتکس فارسی}

 ‎\author{x}‎

 \begin{document}‎
‎ \maketitle‎

‎éÙðôã¾Ïòø­‎ ‎×Ñ÷ÏýöïÑ ôÕÄëð ½Ò Òô¾õ‎
‎ëÕôÃÌ¾òÃù¾ü ô¾ö¾‎ÏÑ éÙð ± ÏÑÀ¾Ñø‎­ ‎Ä¾Àâ ô÷Ç
÷ Êï÷öïþ ½ÕÄé¾Ïø ½Ò »õ ÀÑ½ü ôÌ¾ÕÀø‎­ ‎íôýÃù¾ü ï÷ö¾ï÷õ‎ 
ô÷ÑÏáñëø ÀÕý¾Ñ ïéÄýó¢ ½ýöì Òô¾õ »õ éÑ½ÑÕýÏø íø ÏýïÑ Ì¾×ýø öÑ÷ýó ÷ 
$)t,x(isP\$ Ñ½‎ ‎ýÑ ÀøÏÕÃ »÷Ñýó£‎ ‎À¾ýÏ ôã¾Ïòø‎­ ‎×Ñ÷ÏýöïÑ‎ ‎}noitauqe{nigeb\‎
isP\V+}2^x ap\{}isP\2^ap\{fd\}m2{}2^rabh\{fd\-=}t ap\{}isP\ap\{fd\rabh\i‎
}noitauqe{dne\‎   
‎Ñ½ ÀÑ½ü ÂÄ¾öÕýð ôãýõÒýÑö÷ýÔÎÕÄøíööÏø ½ÕÃ íø ôÏ½ó Àï÷ýýó‎ ‎Ä¾Àâ ½öÑÓü‎ 
‎ÂÄ¾öÕýð¦ ÀøùôýõÏòýð ôãô÷ñ¬ $V$ Ñ½ Äöû¾‎ ‎ÂÄ¾öÕýð‎ ‎ôþÎ÷½ööÏ§ ùÑÊöÏ ½ýõ‎ 
‎í¾Ñ§ ï¾ùþ À¾áÅ ½×ÄÀ¾ø À¾‎ ‎ýÑ ÂÄ¾öÕýð ½òíÄÑýíþ‎ ‎ôþ×÷Ï íø ÏÑ÷½ëâ ½öÑÓü‎ 
‎ÂÄ¾öÕýð‎ ‎ýÑ Àø½Ò½ü ýí¾ü À¾Ñ‎ ‎½ÕÃ¢‎ ‎$)t,x(V$ Ìð íöýó¢ ÏÑ ½ýõ éÙð‎ ‎÷‎ 
‎ÀýÖÄÑ ëÕôÃù¾ü ½ýõ íÄ¾¿‎ ‎éÑÚ ôþíöýó íø $V$‎
‎ýÑ ôÕÄëð ½Ò‎ ‎$t$ ½ÕÃ¢ ÏÑ½ýõÙ÷ÑÃ ôã¾Ïòø‎­ 
‎×Ñ÷ÏýöïÑ Ñ½ ôþÄ÷½õ À¾‎ ‎Õþ Ñ÷Ö ÈÏ½Õ¾Òü ôÄçýÑù¾‎ ‎½÷òýõ‎ 
‎Ñ½ø ý÷ÑÖ ùÑ éýÒýìÏ½õ Àø ùÑ ôã¾Ïòø‎­ ‎ÏýéÑ½öÕýðª Â¾Ñø½ü‎ ‎Ìð íÑÏ¥ ô¾ ÀøÏöÀ¾ð‎  
‎È÷½¿ù¾ýþ ùÕÄýó íø ÀøÙ÷ÑÃ‎ ‎ýÑ Ì¾ÙðÛÑ¿ù¾ü‎ ‎Õ¾Ïø½öÏïÕýÎÄïþ±‎
‎}noitauqe{nigeb\‎ )t(ihprav\)x(isp\=)t,x(isP\‎
 ‎}noitauqe{dne\‎


‎\end{document}
```

Comment: What encoding were the files saved in under DOS? (I’m afraid I’m not familiar enough with Farsi to reverse-engineer the mojibake.) If you can open them in a browser and editor, try copying and saving them as UTF-8. Or convert them to UTF-8 with a program such as `iconv`.

Comment: @Davislor I tried Tex Works, Texmaker, and TexStudio. All have the same issue. With Texmaker I tried UTF-8, but another kind of bizarre symbols appeared like Ѡ�

Comment: No, one need a real, unchanged file. Copy&paste changes the encoding.  If you can't show it you will have to try with iconv yourself.

Comment: @Davislor I don't know so much about iconv. Is there any link that explains it? I guess the problem is due to the character encoding

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you explain or introduce a link that explains iconv?

Comment: You probably have `iconv` on your system if you run Linux, but you can install it on other OSes too: http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/iconv/ You need to know what the original encoding (code page) the files were saved in.

Comment: Again, is there any program on your machine you *can* read the files in? Does pasting from that to an editor and saving a new file in UTF-8 work?

Comment: @Davislor No, I tried all programs that read tex files. I don't know so much about Linux, so I should find someone who can help me with that.

Comment: Do you know what encoding they were saved as originally? Iran Systems? 1097? 1098? 1256? 1259?

Comment: @Saeid ignore tex for the moment: the first thing is to work out what encoding the file is in, so you do not need a tex-specific editor, can you read the files in any editor on any system?

Comment: Or, if you save a copy ending in `.txt` instead of `.tex`, can your browser autodetect the encoding?

Comment: @Davislor I don't know sadly. When I want to open it by Texmaker, this message appears: This file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding UTF-8. Use this encoding: ISO 8851-9. I tried this and other encodings, but in all cases the same issue persists.

Comment: What TeX Editor was your original TeX file written in? If it is either FarsiTeX or Tex-e-Parsi, the `xepersian` package provides python scripts to convert your old files to unicode and/or `xepersian` format. 

If your original file was written using FarsiTeX, you need to use the python script file `ftxe-0.12.py`.

If your original file was written using TeX-e-Parsi, you need to use one of the other python script files provided by the `xepersian` package depending on the format.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi That is the file of book (my translation) published in 2008, and I don't know about the details of the original file. I was told it is written under DOS. I will ask the publisher about the details.

Comment: @Saeid If it was published with fatemi publications, it is most probably TeX-e-Parsi and you can use one of the python scripts provided by the `xepersian` package to convert it to unicode.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi They told me they have used "data processing Tex", and this is the first time I hear that. Maybe they mean TeX-e-Parsi. I will try both. Their original response is " اون قدیما دو نوع تک داشتیم 1. تک شریف 2. تک داده پردازی. فکر کنم ما از تک داده پردازی استفاده می کردیم"

Comment: @Saeid Dadeh Kavi was the company behind Tex-e-Parsi. Seeing how they refer to FarsiTeX as TeX-e-Sharif, I guess when they say Dadeh Pardazi TeX, they really mean TeX-e-Parsi. Anyway, you can use the python script `dkun-0.4.py` to convert it to unicode in the following way: `python dkun-0.4.py file_in.tex file_out.tex` where `file-in.tex` is your original TeX-e-Parsi file and `file-out.tex` is the output unicode file. After that there may need to be for some fine tuning by hand. The python script `dkun-0.4.py` can be downloaded from mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian/dkun-0.4.py

Comment: @VafaKhalighi I really appreciate your help